# 18.04: Headphone & Speaker don't work simultaneously

Tags: sound, headphones, speakers

My PC has both Ubuntu 18.04 & Windows 10. In Windows, I can use headphones and speakers by switching both on the menu; both are working simultaneously.

But in Ubuntu, if headphones are plugged in, the system cannot see my speakers. If I unplug the headphones, the speakers work.

Speakers are plugged in to sound ports on the back of the desktop, and the headphones plug in to the front side jack.

How may I troubleshoot this to solve it?